# How can I know which of the /dev/input/eventX (X=0..7) have the Linux input stream?

Tags: linux, events, input

I am trying to capture linux keyboard/mouse input, and I am reading events from like `/dev/input/event2`. But it seems the input are sometimes directed to `/dev/input/event2`, sometimes to `/dev/input/event3`. I wonder if there is a place I can find out which of the stream has the input?

Comment: Look at `/dev/input/by-id` or `/dev/input/by-path`, they have symbolic links to the right `/dev/input/event<x>`.

Comment: @n.m.: these links aren't everywhere (e.g. they're not in Android).

Answer (score 104):

Just stumbled across this -- rather late in the day.

You can find out the names and other attributes of different devices using:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Comment: my **bluetooth** ipage gamepad is sucessfuly connected to /dev/input/js0 (paired and calibrated with jstest-gtk) but it is not listed in /proc/bus/input/devices **sorry my fault it is listed here, im sorry**

Comment: yeah, this does NOT answer the question

Comment: `cat /proc/bus/input/devices  | grep -P '^[NH]: ' | paste - -`

Answer (score 31):

Using `sudo evtest` is very helpful.
It will list all your input devices by name and corresponding event number. Then you can enter device event number of your interest and monitor its events.

Comment: Source code available at [evtest filetype:c](http://www.google.com/search?q=evtest+filetype%3Ac).

Answer (score 17):

To find out, go to `/dev/input/by-id` or `/dev/input/by-path` and do a
`ls -l` to find out which symlink points to which `event<*>`.

Also, I thought it would be helpful for all those who come across this page to find this helpful [link](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/05/grab-raw-keyboard-input-from-event-device-node-devinputevent/) to some code which captures keyboard events.

Comment: my **bluetooth** gamepad is succesfully conenected as /dev/input/js0 - tested and calibrated with jstest-gtk but it is not located in `/dev/input/by-id` directory and STEAM cant use it (error: no gamepad found) ...

Comment: Unfortunately, both by-id and by-path seem to be broken as they only generate symlinks for one device per model.

Answer (score 7):

Run this in Terminal, it will work just fine:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | awk '/keyboard/{for(a=0;a>=0;a++){getline;{if(/kbd/==1){ print 
$NF;exit 0;}}}}'
```

[Source](http://vincian.tx0.org/links/extra.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that this is case-sensitive. So, if your keyboard is listed as `... Keyboard ...` and not `... keyboard ...`, it won't find it. You need to make this command case-insensitive.

Comment: `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | awk '/[Kk][Ee][Yy][Bb][Oo][Aa][Rr][Dd]/{for(a=0;a>=0;a++){getline;{if(/kbd/==1){ print $NF;exit 0;}}}}'`

Comment: I see a lot of things that aren't meaningfully keyboards showing up registered with the "kbd" handler. The power button, the PC speaker(!)...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late to reply but I hope this is helpful for friends.

“mice” contains mouse input data, but to find the file related to the keyboards we need to check the files in folder “by-path”, keyboards file names end with “**event-kbd**”. We need to find the links to the keyboards, and then we can find the keyboards event file. The following commands can do this automatically for us:

```
kbdEvents=($(ls /dev/input/by-path | grep "event-kbd"))     
for forCounter in "${kbdEvents[@]}"
do
    eventFile=$(readlink --canonicalize "/dev/input/by-path/${forCounter}")     
    # do anything ...
done
```

This code is part of the code for the break time on my personal website : [mazKnez.com](http://mazknez.com/linux-bash-script-to-remind-you-of-the-break-timeresttime/)

Answer (score 1):

Following the others hints and some trial and error as I ain't a bash wizard, this is how I am using to get the inputXX of my bluetooth controller, to use with xboxdrv tool. Any other case that uses the `/dev/input/eventXX` and that shows up in `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` will also work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
event="`sudo cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -Poz '("STK-7007F1"[\s\S]+?)\Kevent\d+'`"
echo $event #event26, for example
```

You may use other commands instead of echo. The "STK-7007FI" is how my controller is named when running `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`. The script will throw a warning regarding a null char or something for some reason beyond my linux commands knowledge, but it works fine even with it.

The -Poz flag in grep is to use multiline regex. The \K is a working alternative for lookbehind. There may be better ways to do it, but that's what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

At least NTFS-3G forbids such names because they can be problematic:

https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blob/a4a837025b6ac2b0c44c93e34e22535fe9e95b27/libntfs-3g/unistr.c#L1517

And judging from your fuseblk mount points, you're using ntfs-3g to mount those partitions. I haven't looked into the code enough to determine if there's a way to switch this checking off.