# Write directly to /dev/input/event5, write to character device file

Tags: c, linux, file, input

My keyboard has a volume control. And I'm trying to directly trigger/emulate a volume up event. Using `xxd -c 24 event5`, I can monitor what the file contains. When I use the actual volume button, it triggers it normally. Below is a C script that writes the exact data that the button sends.

```
int main()
{
    int f = open("/dev/input/event5", O_WRONLY);
    if(f == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not open event5");
        return 1;
    }
    struct input_event e;
    gettimeofday(&e.time, 0);
    e.type = 0x0400;
    e.code = 0x0400;
    e.value = 0x0e9000c00;
    write(f, &e, sizeof(e));

    gettimeofday(&e.time, 0);
    e.type = 0x0100;
    e.code = 0x7300;
    e.value = 0x01000000;
    write(f, &e, sizeof(e));

    gettimeofday(&e.time, 0);
    e.type = 0x0000;
    e.code = 0x0000;
    e.value = 0x00000000;
    write(f, &e, sizeof(e));
    return 0;

}
```

However `xxd -c 24 event5` does not detect the write, nor does the volume-up action trigger on my desktop.

The file is opening fine without error. But I still suspect it's something wrong with the open command. Which leads me to ask

How do you write to this type of file?

```
crw-rw----   1 root input 13, 69 Feb  1 17:26 event5
```

Comment: *“And I'm trying to directly trigger/emulate a volume up event.”* To turn the volume up? Is doing that more directly not an option for some reason?

Comment: @Ryan this is all for educational purposes. Nothing practical.

Comment: do any of the answers to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990978/how-can-i-know-which-of-the-dev-input-eventx-x-0-7-have-the-linux-input-stre

Comment: To generate such events one has to instrument kernel, i.e. write special module.

Comment: Are the `write()` calls actually succeeding?  You're not checking the return value.  It wouldn't surprise me if they were failing with `errno` set to something like `ENOSYS` or `ENOTSUP`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, that completely missed my thought. I'll give look at the errno on that.

Comment: @0andriy Yes, I've seen the tutorials when looking this question up. But is writing to character devices impossible without creating a module?

Comment: And what exactly you are expecting to get from the device which operates IOCTLs and alike?